# Absolute URLs for JS and CSS in Liferay Theme causing problems when behind proxy

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

We all know that we can include custom JS/CSS in theme `portal_normal.vm` as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/custom.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="$css_folder/your_custom.css"></link>
```

Both the variables `$javascript_folder` and `$css_folder` result into an absolute URL.
`http://content.liferay.com/4.3/misc/theme-api-4.3.0.html`

In my situation, the liferay runs behind a proxy server and hence, these absolute URLs are causing me a trouble and the js/css files are NOT getting loaded in the browser.

Not only the files added using these velocity variables, but some other theme related files (`main.css`, `main.js`) are also not loaded into browser with server absolute URLs.

Is there a way to force theme to use relative URLs instead of absolute?

Thanks

Comment: what are the URLs that you're seeing? e.g. do you see internal server names or localhost? It might be a misconfiguration of your proxy or liferay setup, but a bit more information is required to judge. "there are problems with URLs" doesn't qualify

Comment: @Olaf Kock Hi Olaf, I can see the internal server absolute URLs in the page source.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute URLs in general are huge pain in Liferay. Can you afford to specify properties in portal-ext.properties:

- web.server.host
- web.server.protocol
- web.server.port

?

If so this may help you - it should make absolute path respect your proxy configuration. Thought it is not always possible - for instance when you need to access LR instance both through proxy and directly (think e.g. intranet vs extranet).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it solves one part of the story. As you said, specifying web server details makes that LR instance accessible through the proxy every time, routing all the traffic through web server even if we access the internal server directly(intranet). Need something which would set up the LR instance both for intranet as well as for internet users.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think that this is actually impossible. Look at these issues: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-31251 and especially this one https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-32097

Why does it have *minor* priority is beyond my understaning...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache's mod_proxy and forward through http, I suggest that you take a look at the `ProxyPreserveHost On` directive. This forwards the hostname actually used to tomcat (and thus, Liferay).

Another alternative is to use mod_jk or mod_proxy_ajp - they forward the traffic through the ajp protocol, which does this automatically.

In short: Unless otherwise configured (see pdolega's answer) Liferay will use the hostname that a request has been made to. This is determined by Tomcat. And if tomcat only gets proxy requests to an internal host, that's what it resolves to.

The one caveat though is that sometimes there's no request (e.g. in background tasks, emails etc.) and it might be worth to use the same hostname on both ends: Think of an email notification of a message board post: If this goes to intranet- and internet-users, which hostname do you expect to be in the link that is sent out to both kinds of users simultaneously.